# C# - Sort array of struct without using any built-in function, just using loops

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, struct

I have a struct of employee data and it 2 separated fields of first name and last name. i want to sort this array by first name and in case of 2 names are the same then sort them by last name. I already sorted the array by the first name but still cant do it by the last name in case 2 first names are the same. I want to implement this sort without using any built-in functions in .Net such as array.sort() i just want to use loops.

```
public struct EmployeeData
        {
            public char sex;
            public int age;
            public int id1;
            public int id2;
            public int id3;
            public string fname;
            public string lname;
            public int seniority;
        }
    static EmployeeData[] SortByFirstName(EmployeeData[] empdata)
        {
            int min = 0;
            EmployeeData temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < empdata.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i+1; j < empdata.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (empdata[i].fname.Length < empdata[j].fname.Length)
                    {
                        min = empdata[i].fname.Length;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        min = empdata[j].fname.Length;
                    }

                    for (int k = 0; k < min; k++)
                    {
                        if (empdata[i].fname[k] > empdata[j].fname[k])
                        {
                            temp = empdata[i];
                            empdata[i] = empdata[j];
                            empdata[j] = temp;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (empdata[i].fname[k] == empdata[j].fname[k])
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return empdata;

        }
```

Comment: did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Change your sort function to handle both first name and last name.

Where you say

```
else if (empdata[i].fname[k] == empdata[j].fname[k])
    {
         continue;
    }
```

Instead of continuing, sort the two entries by last name..